# Plotting `rnorm` over the top of certain x-axis values

Tags: r, plot

## Background:

I am trying to replicate the below plot. The plot consists of **8** `rnorm()`s each defined as `rnorm(n = 100, mean = varying, sd = 1)`, each one of the 8 stacked over the top of a particular value of the x-axis. For example, over the top of **x-axis value of 1**, there is the following `rnorm`:

`rnorm(n = 100, mean = 11, sd = 1)` OR

over the top of **x-axis value of 2**, there is the following `rnorm`:

`rnorm(n = 100, mean = 12, sd = 1)` (So, only `mean` is varying by one value [i.e., here from 11 to 12].)

## Coding Question:

I have tried the **following R code** to replicate the plot I showing below *without success*:

(I'm wondering how I can fix my R code to reproduce the plot below?)

**NOTE:** I need to plot the actual values of x and y obtained in the manner shown below such that I can pass an `lm` thru the plotted data as shown in the plot below.

```
mean = 11:18     
x = rep( 1:8, 1e2 ) 
y = rnorm(1e2, mean, 1)

plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: `sapply(11:18, rnorm, n = 1e2, sd = 1)`

Comment: @DavidePassaretti, but this doesn't look like the plot I'm trying to replicate?

Comment: Your problem is to create the y variabile, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to easily create a vectorized version of `rnorm()` with respect to the `mean` argument:

```
Vec_rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

y <- Vec_rnorm(1e2, 11:18, 1)
```

You will get a matrix of 100 rows and 8 columns, where each column relates to a specific mean of the Normal r.v.

If you want to get everything as a vector just use `c()`:

```
y <- c(Vec_rnorm(1e2, 11:18, 1))

x <- rep(1:8, each = 1e2)

plot(x, y)

abline(lm(y~x))
```

Comment: You had to iterate over all possible values of the mean using a loop (for, sapply, Vectorize, etc..), because rnorm is not vectorized wrt the mean argument.

Comment: yes, because if you omitted each, then you'd get 1:8, 1:8, 1:8, ... etc one hundred times. But you want 1, 1, 1,..., 2, 2, 2,... etc. It's just a matter of order

Comment: One question Davide, How can get the density of each `rnorm()` stacked over the top off at a specific point on the x-axis?